# Mudanças no servidor não surgem efeito

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp

Tenho uma aplicação rodando em c# com .net 4.5 no IIS 8.
To editando um 
Controller (que é um arquivo .cs).
Porém, editei umas coisas nesse Controller e vi que essas mudanças não estavam se propagando.

Tentei editar a Action desse Controller, tentei editar os parâmetros que esse Controller passa pra View por uma variável "ViewBag".

Nenhuma das mudanças feitas fizeram efeito, aí eu simplesmente apaguei tudo que tinha no Controller e ainda sim consegui acessar as Actions dele.

Então, isso é algum cache? Ou pelo que achei procurando no Google ele "Compila" meu código.

Como eu faço pra ele compilar novamente?
Ou como faço pra ele compilar a cada mudança ou ele compilar sozinho a cada acesso ao Controller?

> Obs.: A aplicação está rodando num servidor online, não local.
>   Lá tenho acesso ao IIS manager remotamente.

Comment: Você está dando [deploy](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment) a cada alteração em seu projeto para o IIS no "servidor online"?

Comment: Primeiro vc deve detalhar como é feito seu processo de Deploy nesse "servidor online".

Comment: O servidor tem um "Web Deploy", então, toda vez que eu fizer alguma alteração devo fazer este deploy?

Comment: @StiveKnx, se você não criou nenhum mecanismo de deploy automatizado, você deve explicitamente repetir o processo de deploy de seu projeto a cada nova versão que deseje enviar para "produção" (servidor online), caso contrário os efeitos das alteração permanecerão apenas em seu projeto local. (Não há magica. Hehe)

Comment: Não é mais simples usar o IIS Express?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve efetuar um Publish do projeto pelo visual studio. Essa opção está disponível clicando com o botão direito no projeto e a opção publish. Você pode dar um publish direto no servidor se tiver acesso. Caso contrário você pode usar o modo Web Deploy Package, que gerará um .zip que você vai implantar em seu servidor IIS no site correspondente.

Veja estes 2 links:

[Importar um Web Deploy Package no IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/import-a-package-through-iis-manager)

[Gerar um Web Deploy Package no Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Fiz esses passos, porém as mudanças continuam não surgindo efeito ... Qualquer mudança feita no controller não surge efeito. Posso até deletar tudo dentro dele e ele continua funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Realmente como conforme comentado, cheque seu processo de deploy.

De forma alguma você deve enviar as alterações do seu arquivo .cs (do Controller) para o servidor, para isso acontecer o que você deve enviar para o servidor são os arquivos .dll gerados pelo build.

Comento isso pois já vi gente que veio de php e asp enviando o arquivo cs para o servidor.

Outra coisa que pode dar problemas parecidos, é se seu servidor está em Load Balance.
Dependendo da configuração, você precisa atualizar as dll em cada nó do cluster. Já vi casos em que atualizaram apenas um dos servidores e a aplicação ficava então atualizada para alguns usuários e para outros não. Isso porque parte dos usuários por causa do balanceamento acessava o servidor com a aplicação atualizada e outra parte com a aplicação desatualizada, o que gerava grande confusão.

Prefira sempre um deploy automatizado.
Espero que o ajude.

Comment: Então esse é meu caso (vindo do php e tendo que mexer num projeto em c#). Não sabia que deveria rodar esse deploy depois de cada mudança .. Tá, e pra fazer esse deploy, somente com visual studio?